# How to solve differential equations using fft?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, fourier-analysis

Can anyone point me to the principles and books/websites about it?

Which properties must the differential equation have that a solution with fft is possible?

Why can it be solved that way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Books**

- Fourier Transformation and Linear Differential Equations by Zofia Szmydt
- An Introduction to Fast Fourier Transform Methods for Partial Differential Equations with Applications by Morgan Pickering

There are also books on Fourier Transforms and also books on PDEs that have sections regarding FFT and PDEs. For example:

- A First Course in Fourier Analysis by avid W. Kammler
- Fourier and Laplace Transforms by R. J. Beerends, H. G. ter Morsche, J. C. van den Berg, E. M. van de Vrie

**Papers**

- [*Fourier collocation method for differential equations*](http://www.math.nus.edu.sg/~matgkv/Lecture6.pdf)
- [*Solving Poisson's Equation using the FFT*](http://www.physics.buffalo.edu/phy410-505-2004/Chapter6/ch6-lec2.pdf)
- [*Introduction to Fast Poisson Solvers*](http://people.freebsd.org/~snb/school/fastpoisson.pdf)
- You can Google and there are many papers in this area (including papers from this year as there is still work going on in this area)

You may also want to check your local college library and Open Courseware as I would imagine you'd find some online materials in this area.

Comment: Deserves another TU!

Comment: @amWhy: Happy POETS day and thank you! :-)